# WPF DataTable Display with Multiple 1-D Arrays - Can't Display Data in Arrays

Tags: c#, arrays, wpf, postgresql, datatable

I have a PostgreSQL database for an embedded logger that has 1 columns of string and the rest Int32[]. I've used Npgsql to pull the data from my database but am having issues displaying the Int32[] (arrays).

When I assign my DataGrid a datatable from my dataset, it displays the 1st image. For right now, my arrays only have 1 element in them, which is what I'd like to display, but I don't understand how to access the element in the datatable.

[image]

Image 2 is from PgAdminIII, which is what I'm looking for.

[image]

Does anyone have an idea of how I can access individual data members in my DataTable so I can properly display my arrays? Is the only option to switch from arrays to single elements?

Code I've used thus far:

```
string connstring = "connectionstring stuff";
NpgsqlConnection conn = new NpgsqlConnection(connstring);
conn.Open();
string sql = "SELECT * FROM error000000000";
// data adapter making request from our connection
NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter(sql, conn);
ds.Reset();
// filling DataSet with result from NpgsqlDataAdapter
da.Fill(ds);
dt = ds.Tables[0];
conn.Close();
dataGrid.DataContext = dt;
```

Comment: This sounds like a silly question, but I have to ask...  Do your arrays always only have one element, or was that happenstance in the example you listed?

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you are seeing *Int32[] Array* instead of the actual content is that `DataGrid` simply calls `ToString` on any non-string type to be displayed.

To control how the `DataGrid`'s columns are displayed, specify them explicitly:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="devicesn" Binding="{Binding devicesn}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="time" Binding="{Binding time}" />
        ...other columns follow here...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

Now, if you can be sure that your arrays will always contain exactly one item each, you could instruct the columns to simply display each array's first item:

```
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="devicesn" Binding="{Binding devicesn}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="time" Binding="{Binding time[0]}" />
        ...other columns follow here...
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

But this seems a dirty approach as it will fail as soon as one array is empty.

Instead, you can use a converter that displays the array contents correctly. Define a separate class `ArrayConverter`:

```
public class ArrayConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        var array = value as int[];
        if (array != null)
        {
            return "{" + String.Join(",", array) + "}";
        }
        return value;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, CultureInfo culture)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

...and reference it in XAML:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <local:ArrayConverter x:Key="ArrayConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False">
    <DataGrid.Columns>
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="devicesn" Binding="{Binding devicesn}" />
        <DataGridTextColumn Header="time" Binding="{Binding time, Converter={StaticResource ArrayConverter}}" />
    </DataGrid.Columns>
</DataGrid>
```

(Note that I tested this using a simple collection, but the syntax should be similar when using DataSets!)